# Unknown publisher on security warning window

Tags: installation, client

i am using VS2008 SP1 for publishing my project.
In the options button Publish Description i have given the publisher name as "Testing WebPage" .
But this is only seen in the the publish.html page after publishing the application.
when this application runs on the client machine then in the security warning window it displays Publisher name as Unknown publisher why is it so?

Its strange for me, the client wont install seeing the untrusted application.
My application also has a  project_Temporarykey.pfx certificate created by default but still no use.

i also referred  an article  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996418.aspx from  Brian Noyes  Microsoft MVP but this also didn't solved my problem.
it didn't affect my application publisher name on warning window...

Can u please how to make my publisher name as i want above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Certificate must be generated by a trusted root certificate authority.

For the list of trusted root certificate authorities see Internet Options (in control panel or Internet Explorer menu):
"Contents" tab/"Certificates" button/"Trusted Root Certification Authorities" tab